# onmouseup + h2 not working

Tags: javascript, onmouseup

I need some help here:

I'm trying to move to another page when I click on the LAST ONE h2 element, but what happens is that it's working with ALL the h2 elements.

Here's the thing:

```
<script>
    function ini(){
        document.location.href='home.php';

        }
</script>
```

the elements:

```
    <h2>Inove.</h2>
    <h2>Evolua.</h2>
<h2>Apareça.</h2>
<h2 onMouseUp="ini()">Destaque-se.</h2>
```

---

that's inside this div:

```
<div class="os-phrases" id="os-phrases">
<h2>Inove.</h2>
<h2>Evolua.</h2>
<h2>Apareça.</h2>
<h2>Destaque-se na</h2>
<h2>V1TR1NE.com.br</h2>
<h2></h2>
<h2></h2>
<h2 onMouseUp="ini()">Iniciar...</h2>
</div>
```

and the css treat it as a child.

```
.os-phrases h2 {
    font-family: 'Dosis', 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 200;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    letter-spacing: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}

.os-phrases h2,
.os-phrases h2 > span {
    height: 100%;
    /* Centering with flexbox */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.os-phrases h2 > span {
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.os-phrases h2 > span > span {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.os-phrases h2 > span > span > span {
    display: inline-block;
    color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-animation: OpeningSequence 5.2s linear forwards;
    -moz-animation: OpeningSequence 5.2s linear forwards;
    animation: OpeningSequence 5.2s linear forwards;
}

.os-phrases h2:nth-child(2) > span > span > span {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
}

.os-phrases h2:nth-child(3) > span > span > span {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 10s;
    animation-delay: 10s;
}

.os-phrases h2:nth-child(4) > span > span > span {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-delay: 15s;
}

.os-phrases h2:nth-child(5) > span > span > span {
    font-size: 150px;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 21s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 21s;
    animation-delay: 21s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-duration: 8s;
}

.os-phrases h2:nth-child(6) > span > span > span {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.os-phrases h2:nth-child(7) > span > span > span {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes OpeningSequence {
    0% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
        letter-spacing: 80px;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    }
    50% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
        letter-spacing: 14px;
        opacity: 0.8;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    85% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
        opacity: 0.8;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
    }
    100% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(130px);
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes OpeningSequence {
    0% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
        letter-spacing: 80px;
        opacity: 0.2;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    }
    50% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
        letter-spacing: 14px;
        opacity: 0.8;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    85% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
        opacity: 0.8;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
    }
    100% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateZ(130px);
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}

@keyframes OpeningSequence {
    0% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
        letter-spacing: 80px;
        opacity: 0.2;
        transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    }
    50% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
        letter-spacing: 14px;
        opacity: 0.8;
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    85% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
        opacity: 0.8;
        transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
    }
    100% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateZ(130px);
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}

.os-phrases h2:nth-child(8) > span > span > span {
    font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-animation: FadeIn 4s linear 28s forwards;
    -moz-animation: FadeIn 4s linear 28s forwards;
    animation: FadeIn 4s linear 28s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes FadeIn { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.8;
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes FadeIn { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.8;
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    }
}

@keyframes FadeIn { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.8;
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    }
}

/* Bold words */
.os-phrases h2:first-child .word3,
.os-phrases h2:nth-child(2) .word2,
.os-phrases h2:nth-child(4) .word1 {
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

I tried to use it as link but I couldn't make it works. The final effect ends in this line (.os-phrases h2:nth-child(8) > span > span > span). Here the "Iniciar..." stops and I want to make it an event on click to take me to page home.php.

Comment: Why don't you just use a link?

Comment: link mess all my css effect

Comment: Then fix those instead of making up new problems by doing this with JavaScript.

Comment: in my case, the easiest thing would be to fix h2.

Answer (score 0):

How does the CSS look like? I guess the problem is in there somewhere. Because the following HTML work fine for me: the message box only pops up when I click the last entry:

```
<script>
function ini(){
  alert('test');
}
</script>
<h2>Inove.</h2>
<h2>Evolua.</h2>
<h2>Apareça.</h2>
<h2 onMouseUp="ini()">Destaque-se.</h2>
```

I tested this with Chrome and Safari. It's not terribly good HTML (in fact it's pretty bad) but it *does* work.